# Pyspark yarn cluster submit error (Cannot run Program Python)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to submit pyspark code with pandas udf (to use fbprophet...)
it works well in local submit but gets error in cluster submit such as

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 41, ip-172-31-11-94.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
 &quot;/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1620263926111_0229/container_1620263926111_0229_01_000001/environment/bin/python&quot;: error=2, No such file or directory
```

my spark-submit code:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python \
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python     \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python     \
--jars jars/org.elasticsearch_elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-7.10.2.jar \
--py-files dependencies.zip   \
--archives ./environment.tar.gz#environment \
--files config.ini \
$1
```

I made environment.tar.gz by conda pack, dependencies.zip as my local packages and
config.ini to load settings

Is there anyway to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use local path:

```sh
  --archives ./environment.tar.gz#environment
```

Publish `environment.tar.gz` on hdfs

```sh
venv-pack -o environment.tar.gz
# or conda pack

hdfs dfs -put -f environment.tar.gz /spark/app_name/
hdfs dfs -chmod 0664 /spark/app_name/environment.tar.gz
```

And change argument of spark-submit

```sh
  --archives hdfs:///spark/app_name/environment.tar.gz#environment
```

More info: [PySpark on YARN in self-contained environments](https://gist.github.com/seanorama/094451c21008b72daa1ee8cbd706f2ba)